# How to register multiple RouterFunctions in Spring 5 webflux via RouterFunctionMapping?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

Based on the webflux documents, it is possible to scan the RouterFunctions with RouterFunctionMapping:

> RouterFunctionMapping — detects one or more RouterFunction beans in the Spring configuration, combines them via RouterFunction.andOther, and routes requests to the resulting composed RouterFunction.

Are there any good samples for registering the handlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create as much RouterFunction beans as you want:

```
@Configuration
public class RoutesConfig {
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction helloRoutesV1() {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.path("/v1/hello-world"),
                request -> ok().body(fromObject("Hello World v1!")));
    }

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction helloRoutesV2() {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.path("/v2/hello-world"),
                request -> ok().body(fromObject("Hello World v2!!!")));
    }
}
```

Comment: I though so too, but when multiple beans were defined, the httpServer initialization was failing with:

`Parameter 0 of method httpServer in config.WebConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
 - rootRouterFunction: defined by method 'rootRouterFunction' in class path resource [RouterConfiguration.class]
 - productRouterFunction: defined by method 'productRouterFunction' in class path resource [RouterConfiguration.class]`

Comment: Perhaps config.WebConfiguration is your configuration and it has httpServer(...) method. As you can see Spring don't know what to inject to this method so you have to rewrite this method or use single RouterFunction bean.
I build and run my code without any errors. Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE. I used project template generated by https://start.spring.io/ and added RoutesConfig.java. It is enough to run and test it.

Comment: Thanks... this is kind of strange. In the WebConfiguration, I only had the httpServer initialization as follow :
`...
    @Bean
    fun httpServer(routerFunction: RouterFunction<ServerResponse>): HttpServer? {
        val httpHandler = RouterFunctions.toHttpHandler(routerFunction)
        val adapter = ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(httpHandler)
        val server = HttpServer.create(
                environment.getProperty(SERVERHOST),
                Integer.valueOf(environment.getProperty(SERVERPORT))
        )
        server.newHandler(adapter)
        return server
...    
`

Comment: I guess it not needed anymore with the GA release. When the @EnableWebFlux annotation is removed, the beans were discovered